# How to conditionally format text in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting, m

Is there a way to conditionally format my table so I can add a bar like below? (it was created in excel)

Image I want to create:
[image: Image I want to create]

I am currently stuck with the following - I highlighted the dates but need to know how I can highlight the holidays in my table with that grey color. (the picture below uses Thanksgiving as the example). My goal is to highlight each individual holiday in the table in grey.

Image I need to conditionally format
[image: Image I need to conditionally format]

Here is what I tried with the formula provided below:
[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkmpx.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a date dimension that has an attribute like isHoliday.
2. Create a measure where you specify the color in the Hex Code format ("#A1A1A1")
   for instance:

   ```
    measure_color_coding_holiday = SWITCH ( TRUE (), 'Date'[IsHoliday] = "yes", "#808080", 'Date'[IsHoliday] = "No", "#FFFFFF" )
   ```
3. Go to the conditional formatting for the column > Background Color. Choose Field value and pick the new measure.

/Tom

Comment: How do I create the date dimension? I am extremely new to powerbi so here is what I tried (look above)